# Excel Functions (Average, Standard Deviation, etc) with multiple nested IFS

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested, nested-if

I am having difficulty calculating descriptive statistics based on multiple conditions in Excel.

Here's a subset of the dataset:

```
A   B
1   2   

1   3
3   1
1
```

The blanks indicate missing data - **I cannot rename the blanks (e.g., -999 or NaN)**

Let's say I want to calculate the average. I know that the true average **for values in column A** which have an entry in both columns A and B is 1.67 (based on filtering the data to rows which have entries in both columns).

I have tried a series of functions to account for this condition (e.g., calculate the average of column A for values with an entry in both columns A and B) and the only function that works is `AVERAGEIFS`. However, I cannot rely on this because I want to use the code for any function, e.g., `STDEV`, for which an `FUNCTIONIFS` function does not (yet) exist.

Here's what I've tried, with no luck:

[image]

Here's the code for ease of copying+pasting:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A:A,A:A, ">=0",B:B,">=0")
=AVERAGE(IF(A:A >=0,IF(B:B >=0,A:A)))
=AVERAGE(IF(AND(A:A >=0,B:B >=0),A:A))
=IF(A:A >=0,IF(B:B >= 0,AVERAGE(A:A)))
=IF(AND(A:A>=0,B:B>=0),AVERAGE(A:A))
=AVERAGE(IF((A:A>=0)*(B:B),A:A))
```

To recap, there are three conditions that are necessary:

**1. I need to reference the whole column (e.g., A:A) rather than index a subset of it (e.g., A1:A50).**
2. I need to include missing values as blanks
3. I cannot rely on AVERAGEIFS because I am looking to generalise the code to any function (e.g., STDEV)

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you calculating the average? Isn't the average of the above where both columns populated 1.83?

Comment: It's the average of values in column A which have an entry for column A and B. Have made that clearer in the text - apologies.

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As follows:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A2:A6<>"",IF(B2:B6<>"",A2:A6)))
```

Enter as array formula with Ctrl + Shift and Enter.

Same principle for STDEV

```
=STDEV.P(IF(A2:A6<>"",IF(B2:B6<>"",A2:A6)))
```

Enter as array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Clearly, delete the row references for entire columns e.g.    `=AVERAGE(IF(A:A<>"",IF(B:B<>"",A:A)))` .

---

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A:A<>"",IF(B:B<>"",A:A,""),""))
=STDEV(IF(A:A<>"",IF(B:B<>"",A:A,""),""))
```

Enter as array formulas CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER.

Hope that helps.